# Yii2 Advanced: Request return 404 error from a generated CRUD view

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am testing `Yii 2 advanced`, i have created a view from CRUD and everything works fine, i can even get to see the index view, but when i create another CRUD which model is called `CArea`, it gets created but i cannot get to the view because it returns a 404 error response, the controller is generated with the name `CAreaController` and search is called `CAreaSearch`

I have been using `Yii 1` and i have never encountered this error, if anyone would explain why it doesn't work, it would be appreciated

this is the generated controller

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\CArea;
use common\models\search\CAreaSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * CAreaController implements the CRUD actions for CArea model.
 */
class CAreaController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all CArea models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CAreaSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single CArea model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new CArea model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CArea();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing CArea model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing CArea model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the CArea model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return CArea the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = CArea::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you use `CArea` and not simply `Area`?  Yuo have created the Model and the CRUD using Gii (for Yii2)?

Comment: `CArea` stands for `Coded Area` in database, and yes, Model and CRUD were created using Gii

Comment: Please show me the code when you call the view ? (your request , URL)

Comment: @scaisEdge url: http://localhost/backend/web/index.php?r=carea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think you should use  his way for accessing your view

```
  localhost/backend/web/index.php?r=c-area
```

This because Yii2 routing notation need to format the camelCase in `-` (minus) separated string

Comment: well, i didn't remember that point, it gave me a different error but it was because the view was not found, i just had to change the name of the folder like `c-area` to fix it and then it works, although i though gii would have added `-` (minus) already on generating files

Comment: downvote for a correct and accepted  answer  It's pretty strange (expecially after One and Half Year)